# How to ask Jackson to deserialize html escape chars with in text?? Tried all config but no luck

Tags: deserialization, jackson, html-escape-characters

Jackson Deserializer issue ::

How to parse html escapse charecters?

For example :: I need to deserialze json string.

```
{ "deployvirtualmachineresponse" : {"errorcode" : 431, "errortext" : "you "-" and me"}  }

Please @See "errortext" : "you "-" and me" above.
```

Need:: errortext must be parsed with "-".

How to tell jackson to treat ["you "-" and me"] as one string while parsing as it fails on "-"??

Answer (score 0):

You can't: what you have is not valid JSON, one MUST escape double-quote characters with backslash ('\') character.